# How to assign different click function to each face of the cube in react three fibre

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber

Hi I have a simple Cube component made with *react three fibre*.

```
 import {useState,useRef} from 'react';
   import { useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber';
   const Box = ({props}) =>{
    const ref = useRef()
    const [hovered, hover] = useState(false)
    
    const boxClick = () =>{
        alert('clicked the object')
    }
    return ( 
      <mesh
        {...props}
        ref={ref}
        onClick={boxClick}
        scale={2}
        onPointerOver={(event) => hover(true)}
        onPointerOut={(event) => hover(false)}>
        <boxGeometry args={[1.5, 1.5, 1.5]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial color={hovered ? 'yellow' : 'orange'} />
      </mesh>
    )
  }
  export default Box;
```

I am importing the Box compoent in App.js and using it this way-

```
    function App() {

  const [boxes,setBoxes] = useState(0);
  const box1Click = () =>{
    setBoxes(() =>boxes+1)
    alert(boxes)
  }
  return (
   <Canvas className='main-canvas'>

      <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
      <spotLight position={[5, 155, 10]} angle={0.15} penumbra={1} />
      <pointLight position={[-100, -200, -100]} />
      <Box position = {[0 ,0,0]}  />  

    </Canvas>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Right now I can click the cube and it runs the boxClick function properly. What I want to assign different click function to each face of the cube.

Comment: Do you really need the cube? you could take six planes position them in a cube form and assign an onclick prop to each plane

Answer (score 1):

You can draw six planes and change the rotation or the position each time to construct a cube..

```
const Plane = (props) => {
    const ref = useRef();
    const texture = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, "/images/wood.png");

useFrame((state) => {
    if (props.rotateX) ref.current.rotation.x = props.rotateX;
    if (props.rotateY) ref.current.rotation.y = props.rotateY;
    if (props.rotateZ) ref.current.rotation.z = props.rotateZ;
    // ref.current.rotation.x += 0.01;
    // ref.current.rotation.y += 0.01;
});

return (
    <mesh ref={ref} {...props}>
        <planeGeometry />
        <meshBasicMaterial
            color="red"
            side={THREE.DoubleSide}
            opacity={props.opacity}
            transparent
            visible={props.visible}
            map={texture}
        />
    </mesh>
);
```

};

And then add them to your scene

```
<Suspense fallback={null}>
    <Box position={[3, 3, 0]} />

    <Plane
        args={[2, 2]}
        position={[0.5, 0, 0.5]}
        rotateX={Math.PI / 2}
        opacity="0.5"
        visible={true}
    />
    <Plane
        args={[2, 2]}
        position={[0.5, 0.5, 1]}
        opacity="0.8"
        visible={true}
    />
    <Plane
        args={[2, 2]}
        position={[0, 0.5, 0.5]}
        rotateY={Math.PI / 2}
        opacity="1"
        visible={true}
    />
    {/** ... */}
</Suspense>
```